# how to get data,message and status from http client response

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

When I make a http call, I use my own http which extends httpclient. here is get method:

```
return this.httpClient.get(environment.newApiEndpoint + url).map((resp) => resp['data']);
```

as you see, I transform response and only return data from it. but i also want to return 'message' and 'status' . but maybe only 'message'. what do I have to do in the `map` so that i can achieve my purpose?

Comment: remove it, and let the caller decide what it wants to extract from the response body? (and thus let the caller use the real HttpClient directly, which is flexible enough)

Comment: This was the code when I moved in to a new project. and this is how so many http calls are being made. so i have no other option.

Comment: Deprecate this class, and recommend using the standard HttpClient for all new code/update?

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend you to use the standard [httpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) supported by Angular.

As you might or might not know, you can easily get the full response using `httpClient` by simply doing this:

```
return this.httpClient.get<any>(`${environment.newApiEndpoint}url`, {
  observe: 'response'
});
```

It may be a hassle to change everything to `httpClient`, so I would recommend you to keep the rest as the way it was, and only migrate the methods which require you to observe the full http response body.